# ng-options first position value second position key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, html

I have an array which I want to iterate using ng-options that looks like this

array[array[2],array[2],array[2],array[2],array[2]]

The first position is the username and the second position is code number assosiated with that code like so

{John doe, 234123}, {Jane doe , 123456}

The problem is I don't know how I would reference the array positions.

How would I use ng-options so my html can look like

```
 <option value = "234123"> John doe </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean is:

[ ["John doe", 234123], ["Jane doe" , 123456] ]

The select would be:

```
<select ng-options="array[1] for array[0] as array in outerArray"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<select ng-model="user" ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in users"></select>
```

Please check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jxtjjSHbegTT3HyAhXwl?p=preview)